# How to install Atom editor's 'remote-edit' package?

Tags: atom-editor

I'm using Atom editor and I want to edit files in the remote server, the '[remote-edit](https://atom.io/packages/remote-edit)' package seems may solve my problem. But I can't find any information on how to install it, any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all in the [documentation](http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/atom-packages/):

1. From the Atom menu, click on `Preferences > Install`, search for `remote-edit`, click *“Install”*
2. Use the command-line `apm install remote-edit`
3. Somewhere between pure GUI and command-line is the [command palette](http://flight-manual.atom.io/getting-started/sections/atom-basics/#command-palette.). Once triggered, type *“install packages”, then follow the steps from 1.)